# Kubernetes minikube setup upgrade

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I am trying to run my kubernetes setup to latest 1.25.0 version

```
minikube start --vm-driver="hyperv" --memory=8192 --hyperv-virtual-switch="Default Switch" --kubernetes-version v1.25.0
```

but its throwing below error:

```
stderr:
W0929 10:37:40.950826    3988 common.go:84] your configuration file uses a deprecated API spec: "kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2". Please use 'kubeadm config migrate --old-config old.yaml --new-config new.yaml', which will write the new, similar spec using a newer API version.
```

This setup is on windows and i have already changed the kubectl.exe and kubeadm.exe to latest version of 1.25

Also, i have executed `minikube delete`

Answer (score 0):

to overcome this , i had to uninstall old minikube and install the latest one. which solved the issue.